# Jquery UI Tabs -- Content is not refreshed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, tabs

I am running into a weird behavior and would like to get your inputs. I spent half of the day figuring this out and trying various options but no luck.

This is MVC.

I have 2 Tabs.

General and Profile.

On top right of this page I have a dropdown list with list of profiles for this user.

By default, once user's signin, they are shown the General Tab, and on click of Profile I make a call to get the profile details like first name, lastname, etc and display them.

While user is on the profile tab, they can  select a different profile from the dropdownlist on top.

The problem is when a profile is selected from the dropdown I make an ajax call and then display the contents in this profile tab. Due to some reason this content never shows up and it always displays the old profile data. I thought it might be caching the data but the cache is set to false for both these tabs. The profile tab doesn't refresh at all even though I when I debug the cshtml file I see latest data coming through but it doesn't render.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
        <div id="mainUserPDTab">
        <div id="UserPDTab">
        <ul>
        <li>
        <a class="tab" href="@Url.Action("UserDetails", "CustomerSupport", new { signOnId = @Model.SignOnId, internalId = @Model.InternalId, userAgentGuid = @Model.UserAgentGuid })">
        <span>General</span>
        </a>
        </li>
        @if (Model.Profiles != null)
        {
        <li><a class="tab" href="@Url.Action("UserProfileDetails", "CustomerSupport", new {signOnId = @Model.ProfileSignOnId, internalId = @Model.ProfileInternalId, userAgentGuid = @Model.ProfileUserAgentGuid})">
        <span>Profile</span>
        </a>
        </li>
        }

        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

        2).js file
        $('#mainUserPDTab').tabs({
        cache: false,
        select: function (event, ui) {
        checkSession();
        var $curr_panel = $(ui.panel);
        $curr_panel.find('.date').datepicker();
        }
        });
        $('#UserPDTab').tabs({
        cache: false,
        select: function (event, ui) {
        checkSession();
        var $curr_panel = $(ui.panel);
        $curr_panel.find('.date').datepicker();
        }
        });
        3) Dropdown click ajax call
        $("button#viewProfiles").live("click", function () {
        var val = $('.ddrelUsers option:selected').val().split("|");
        var signOnId = val[0];
        var internalId = val[1];
        var useragentGuid = val[3];



        var action = "UserProfileDetails?signOnId=" + signOnId + "&internalId=" + internalId + "&userAgentGuid=" + useragentGuid + "&fromprofile=true";
        $.ajax({
        url: action, //$(this).attr('href'),
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function () {
        checkSession();
        },             
        success: function (result) {
        if ($.trim(result) != '' && result.indexOf('INACTIVESESSION') > -1) {
        window.location.href = "../SignOn";
        return false;
        } else {

        $('#mainUserPDTab').tabs('select', 2);



        }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {

        }

        });
```

Comment: I also did try below to refresh when I get success from ajax call.
 $('#mainUserPDTab').tabs('load', 1);
The problem with above is  its calling the action twice and it resets the data back to the original profile.

Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I got it resolved by adding a dummy div tag and then injecting the html from ajax response into this. thanks